# is there any refresh needed to update `du` command results?

Tags: linux

I have a disk of size `80G` I ran `du` to find that I have a directory which consumed about `60G` so I found the file which caused all this a log file (had size of 60G) I deleted it and now `df` shows that indeed this directory size is reduced.  but even after restarting the offending process the `du` still show that the disk is full.  Does `du` needs any refresh or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`du` may not be the best too for checking how much space is left in different partitions, I'd use:

- `df -H` or `df -HT` (T to see filesystem types)
- `baobab` (Disk Usage Analyzer)  - Shows a nice graphical display and directory sizes, just watch for which folders are mounted on which partitions (`df` or `mount` reveals those)

It's also possible that deleting the file just moved it to a "trash" somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

If that log file is not there anymore it sounds like du is picking up other mounted devices try running.
`du -hx` or `du -h --exclude /media/mounted_devices`